# Kotlin clarification about @ symbol and return postfixes

Tags: kotlin

I am confused about the meaning usage of the next syntax.

1. What does exactly do placing the postfixes "async" and "lazy" after a "return"?

   ```
   return async

   return lazy
   ```
2. What does the "@" symbol mean here?

   ```
   return@async

   return@lazy

   return@withContext
   ```

About the "@" symbol, does it have a special naming in Kotlin? so I can better locate all the ways to use it in the documentation?

What is the difference between adding @ and not using it? so:

```
"return async" vs "return@async"
```

Comment: please check:
kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-at-labels

Comment: @API_1024 These constructs with @ depend on the context (the rest of the code). I answered with my best guesses but it would be better if you provided more complete snippets, so I could explain what happens in the specific case you have seen.

Comment: I'm wondering it it would be better to edit this question/accepted answer to remove the first point, which is a misunderstanding, and leave the 2nd point, which is a good question. The first part just adds a distraction for other people that will read this.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip The question is not only about the "@" symbol, but also about the postfixes after the "return" keyword, such as "return async{...." or "return lazy{...". For me is a very confusing syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What does exactly do placing the postfixes "async" and "lazy" after a "return"?

This is ***not*** special syntax in Kotlin with the specific words "async" or "lazy". So it is not really a "postfix for the `return` keyword". ***After a space***, what follows the return is always the *value* that you want to return:

- `return 42` returns the value 42
- `return async` returns the value of the expression `async` (which is probably a variable that has been declared earlier in the code)
- `return async { 42 }` returns the value of the expression `async { 42 }`.

The meaning of the expression `async { 42 }` here is unrelated to the `return` in itself. You could see the same expression assigned to a variable for instance: `val deferred = async { 42 }`. `async` is simply a library function from the kotlinx.coroutines library (it's just my guess by the way, maybe the code you've seen declares variables/functions of this name, but it's hard to tell without more context). Have a look at the [doc of the `async` function here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) if you're interested.

> 2. What does the "@" symbol mean here?

The `return` keyword by default returns from the closest enclosing function declared with the `fun` keyword. Lambdas don't count, because they are not declared with `fun`.

Therefore, `return`-ing from inside a lambda will by default (without `@`) return from an enclosing function rather than just the "local" lambda (as opposed to what happens in Java). This is why we call them *non-local returns*.

Using a *qualified* return with a *label* (`return@label`) allows to change this default behaviour and specify what you want to return from explicitly.
See the doc about [return at labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-at-labels), it contains many examples.

The specific examples you gave:

```kotlin
return@async
return@lazy
return@withContext
```

would need a bit more context to understand them. But I assume that you have seen them used inside lambdas that are a parameter of `async`/`lazy`/`withContext` function calls. What follows the `@` here is called an *implicit label* which tells the compiler that this `return` is supposed to return from this lambda instead of returning from the closest enclosing `fun`.

#### Other notes

Note that the `@` symbol here is not an *annotation* like you could see elsewhere like `@JvmDefault` or `@OptIn(...)`, it is instead a *label* reference.

Note that both a label and a return value can be combined: `return@myLabel 42` returns the value 42 from the function qualified by the label `myLabel`.